# Ontology for proper nouns

Tags: nlp, ontology

I want to filter texts according to some specific topic. This may require semantics for proper nouns. e.g  if given topic is 'tv series', it should also provide me with texts related to 'game of thrones', or 'friends', or any other tv series. e.g 2 if given topic is 'adobe', it should provide texts related to 'photoshop',etc. Can someone suggest some ways to proceed for the same

Comment: Look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebase

Comment: how many topics do you have? how broad are they? you could also look at DbPedia / Wikipedia categories

Comment: Might want to use [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) (for [document classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification)), [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) (and [LSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) or [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation)), or [semantic similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) (perhaps with [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet)).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Language Graph provided by Idilia. It contains an extensive coverage of proper nouns. For example, "game of thrones" is connected to "television program" and Photoshop is connected to Adobe. Idilia also has word sense disambiguation technology that maps text to those senses. Start at [Language Graph](http://www.idilia.com/developer/language-graph/).

Disclosure: I work for Idilia.